# Permanently add item to $PATH using Ansible on RHEL7

Tags: rhel, path, ansible

> **What specific syntax must be changed below in order for Ansible to successfully add `/home/another-user/bin` to the $PATH variable on a RHEL 7 VM?**

**Current Version of Playbook:**

The playbook we are using sets a variable for the `/home/another-user/bin` and then uses the variable to add a line to `/etc/environment` as follows:

```
vars:
  extra_path: /home/another-user/bin
vars_files:
  - myVars.yaml
#Other stuff

- name: Update /etc/environment for newly loaded apps
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/environment
    line: "export PATH={{ extra_path }}:$PATH"
    owner: root
  become: true
  become_user: root
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: "{{ root_pass_word }}"
```

**BAD RESULT**

The problem is that the above example is destroying all existing entries in the $PATH so that basic commands like `cat` and others are no longer recognized:

```
[my-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ echo $PATH
/home/another-user/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/my-user/.local/bin:/home/my-user/bin
[my-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ cat /etc/environment
-bash: cat: command not found
[my-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$
```

I did find other examples using regular expressions here and on Stack Overflow, but those examples causes the same problem of `command not found` by munging the `/etc/environment` in one way or another.

Comment: Your `$PATH` is not defined in the first place. No idea why. As a workaround add `:/bin:/usr/bin` to it - `cat` is placed in some of these paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/etc/environment` file is not evaluated as a shell script. To quote from its [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/environment.d.5.html) (rearranged for clarity):

> The configuration files contain a list of "KEY=VALUE" environment
> variable assignments, separated by newlines.
>
> The right hand side of
> these assignments may reference previously defined environment
> variables, using the "${OTHER_KEY}" and "$OTHER_KEY" format.
>
> ...
>
> No
> other elements of shell syntax are supported.

So, you have an `export` command in the inserted line, which is invalid for the `/etc/environment` file. Change from:

`line: "export PATH={{ extra_path }}:$PATH"`

to

`line: "PATH={{ extra_path }}:$PATH"`

and it should work correctly.

---

Something else to check here is the new path you're adding, which seems to be `/home/another-user/bin`. User's home directories are usually protected with a 700 permission, so the contents would only be visible to the owner (i.e. the user corresponding to that home directory). `/etc/environment` applies to all users, but is the new path configuration relevant for all users? Something to consider looking into.

Answer (score 2):

I found the accepted answer does not work on Centos7. Usually I find RHEL7 and Centos7 have the same functionality at this level.

`/etc/environment` was empty and was behaving exactly as described in this [Ubuntu doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment) (yes I double checked and the VM is definitely Centos7). It was not expanding the `$PATH` variable and that caused the path to break as it did not like the literal `$` in it.

I found the recommended solution from that doc of adding a script to `/etc/profile.d/` does work as expected i.e.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/some/other/path' > /etc/profile.d/my_path.sh
```

or using the [ansible copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html)

```
- name: Add to PATH
  copy:
    content: "export PATH=$PATH:/some/other/path"
    dest: "/etc/profile.d/my_path.sh"
```

As I don't have any RHEL7 VMs I am unable to test if this solution also works there.